# Are there any large maritime data sets?

Tags: data, marine, maritime-map

Needs to have from port, to port, and time stamps for each (arrival, departure times)

Is there a dataset with all of this, or will I need to combine some other ones?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=maritime+gps+tracker&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=AIS+ship+tracking+database will highlight the AIS database. It is a record of GPS transmissions, at approximately 5-minute intervals, of the world's commercial vessels.  You would have to figure out when the ship might be in port.

Comment: Try asking this on the [Open Data SE](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/).  You might be able to get some more resources in addition to what's been posted here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trove of data here:
http://www.nauticalcharts.noaa.gov/csdl/mbound.htm
Also, a similar question was asked:
[What are the existing datasets of world maritime routes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104450/what-are-the-existing-datasets-of-world-maritime-routes)