# Global shipping network datasets for download?

Tags: shapefile, data, network, download, maritime-map

Does anyone know if global shipping routes for free download (preferably ESRI shapefile) exist? I would need them for my research only as a background presentation on the world image. They can be rough presentation, I would need something like this: http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?layers=12c0789207e64714b9545ad30fca1633&useExisting=1

I have already tried the link of Global Shipping Lane Network from Oak Ridge National Labs (mentioned in this post [What are the existing datasets of world maritime routes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104450/what-are-the-existing-datasets-of-world-maritime-routes)), but the link does not function anymore.

Comment: What have you already tried? A search for 'Global shipping routes GIS' returns several results...including  https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=89035d71182d4079ae8090eadf9db8a2

Comment: I have tried to download this one already, but its is only for Californian coast (see comments on this link). I did the research before asking, but can not find anything relevant.

Comment: I know that Lloyds List (http://www.lloydslist.com/ll/) offer historic shipping routes back until the 18th century. I'm not sure whether they're available for nowadays. Maybe http://www.lloydslist.com/ll/topic/data-hub/ would be a starting point, howver, the links behind the data hub are currently not available.

Comment: @Ursulka Siete Where you successful in your search?  I only managed to find some historical shipping data (as in 200 years old).

Comment: @Enzo No, nothing new since than. My idea was to make a map of a certain area with shipping rooutes as a background, but as i didn't get any data I abandoned the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link, do give credits to authors

https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/globalmarine/data

Answer (score -1):

Please see the link below. So far it has been the best resource yet for shipping fairways.
https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/shipping-fairways-lanes-and-zones-for-us-waters